# Read PS file from Java

Tags: java, filereader, postscript

I have an incoming file as Postcript, all I need is to read it from java to find out one information available in it.
Is it possible from java to read the .PS file line by line ?

I have googled a lot and found I have to get Ghostscript binaries and then only it is possible but i really need someones expert comment here please!!!

I tried converting my PS file to PDF, but no luck!!!

gswin32c -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=test.pdf test.ps

Comment: PostScripts .ps is text. So yes, piece of cake. Try it first with a programmer's editor like JEdit or Notepad++ understanding Unix line endings.

Comment: PostScript is a text based format - you can read it line by line but I'm not sure that you'll want to.  Ghostscript will convert it to, as you said, a PDF or other things including [text](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.19/VectorDevices.htm#TXT) if you just want the data.

Comment: OK, actually the point is I am about to get printer name inside the PS file and so I have to read it to find the printer name and then issue my print command.

Comment: What makes you think the PostScript program contains a printer name ? It generally won't. Do you have an example file ? If your workflow is such that the PostScript is reliably similar then, as already pointed out, you can just search the PostScript program for whatever it is you are looking for. Note that PostScript is NOT text, it can contain binary data, as well as the language itself having a binary sequence mode.

Comment: @KenS You are right, but one of connected application in my domain is genarating the PS file and putting printer name in it and then my code have to read it and find the printer name from it and then move forward.....its a kind of project..    All I want is java code to read that PS and lookup for printer name, just like we read file from bufferedreader etc

Comment: Well without seeing an example its pretty hard to comment, but it sems to me that stdunbar and Joop Eggen are correct, just open the file and look for the printer name. You don't need Ghostscript, and attempting to use it for ths purpose is massive overkill, it will also be hard, you will need to understand PostScript programming as well as interfacing to a C library.